# stdout, stderr, and what else? (going insane parsing slapadd output)

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, stdout, stderr

I am using `slapadd` to restore a backup. That backup contains 45k entries which takes a while to restore so I need to get some progress update from `slapadd`. Luckily for me there is the `-v` switch which gives an output similar to this one:

```
added: "mail=1@test.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org" (00003d53)
added: "mail=2@test.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org" (00003d54)
added: "mail=3@test.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org" (00003d55)
.########              44.22% eta 05m05s elapsed             04m spd  29.2 k/s 
added: "mail=4@test.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org" (00003d56)
added: "mail=5@test.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org" (00003d57)
added: "mail=6@test.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org" (00003d58)
added: "mail=7@test.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org" (00003d59)
```

Every N entries added, `slapadd` writes a progress update output line (`.########              44.22% eta 05m05s elapsed ...`) which I want to keep and an output line for every entry created which I want to hide because it exposes people's email address but still want to count them to know how many users were imported

The way I thought about hiding emails and showing the progress update is this:

```
$ slapadd -v ... 2>&1 | tee log.txt | grep '########'
# => would give me real-time progress update
$ grep "added" log.txt | wc -l
# => once backup has been restored I would know how many users were added
```

I tried different variations of the above, and whatever I try I can't grep the progress update output line.

I traced `slapadd` as follows:

```
sudo strace slapadd -v ...
```

And here is what I get:

```
write(2, "added: \"mail=3@test.org"..., 78added: "mail=3@test.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org" (00000009)
) = 78
gettimeofday({1322645227, 253338}, NULL) = 0
_########    44.22% eta 05m05s elapsed      04m spd  29.2 k/s    ) = 80
write(2, "\n", 1
)
```

As you can see, the percentage line isn't sent to either `stdout` or `stderr` (FYI I have validated with known working and failing commands that `2` is `stderr` and `1` is `stdout`)

**Q1: Where is the progress update output line going?

Q2: How can I grep on it while sending stderr to a file?**

Additional info: I'm running `Openldap 2.4.21` on `ubuntu server 10.04`

**1st update: potentially relevant info**

From
http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-bugs/200903/msg00235.html

("meter" being what I called above the "progress update output line")

```
> No, the code only enables the meter if stdout (was: stderr) is a tty, so
> redirecting it anywhere disables it.  The meter was enabled both by
> "slapadd -l file" and "slapadd<  file", but "cat file | slapadd" did
> disable it.  IMHO not exactly an obvious way..
```

Still my questions remain as I don't know what to do with that additional info.

Comment: strace again and look which file/device belongs to filehandle 2.

Comment: Don't know how to do it so it will take me a bit of time to find out. In the meantime can you look at the update I put in my question to see if you can advise further from there? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been bitten by a funny behaviour of `slapadd`. There was a discussion on the developer's mailing list about it. Bottom line is that the pogress meter seems to get disabled when redirecting stderr *or* is only enabled when STDIN is a tty (I wasn't able to reach a definitive conclusion based on a few google searches - seems you need to dive into the code!).

Other than that, you're on the right track. For Q2; I'm not so sure about your question here, but to redirect STDERR to a file, just do `slapadd -v ... 2>YOURFILE`. This way you can still grep on STDOUT (1).

Comment: I can indeed redirect `stderr` to a file in which case I get the `added: "mail=...` lines and I can count the number of users imported. However I loose the meter line :( Honestly why would you output the meter line to something different than `stderr` or `stdout`, what's the point of doing this?

Comment: Because it is useless for other programs in the pipe. But I see that you have a use case for that. I haven't tried if you could grab the data from /dev/console or /dev/ttyX while you _not_ redirect the output?

Comment: I see your point, but in my opinion it would be better to have the meter sent to `stdout` and the emails to `stderr` to facilitate the parsing of these 2 outputs. Anyway, could you give me directions as to how reading data from `dev/console` or `/dev/ttyX` please?